# centos 8 sdkmanager update tools failed

Tags: android-sdk-manager, centos8

I use the latest commandlinetool

```
sudo curl https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-7302050_latest.zip -o android-sdk.zip
sudo yum install unzip
sudo unzip android-sdk.zip -d .
```

while trying to Update tools,failed

```
sudo ./cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager "tools"
```

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in
> your PATH. Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to
> match the location of your Java installation.

but I have already set JAVA_HOME and JDK

```
sudo tee /etc/profile.d/jdk1.8.0.sh <<EOF
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_261
export PATH=\$PATH:\$JAVA_HOME/bin
EOF
```

and can verity PATH and JAVA_HOME

```
# echo $PATH
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.1.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_261/bin:/root/bin

# echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/jdk1.8.0_261
```

anyone can help?

Comment: Is `JAVA_HOME` set for you or for `root`? Does it contain a `java` executable?

Comment: @underscore_d ,I set JAVA_HOME for root, [root@mail android_sdk]# echo $JAVA_HOME, it print /opt/jdk1.8.0_261

Comment: @underscore_d, yes ,java is under [/opt/jdk1.8.0_261/bin]

Comment: `sudo bash` is your friend (for power-users there is `su -`). Before that `xhost +local:` might be useful, if you wish to run GUI-applications as root.

Answer (score 0):

can not use sudo,because
in file .../cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager

```
# Determine the Java command to use to start the JVM.
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
        # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    fi
    if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
        die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: $JAVA_HOME

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
    fi
else
    JAVACMD="java"
    which java >/dev/null 2>&1 || die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
```

when I run

```
sudo which java 
which: no java in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

and below code is ok

```
./cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager "tools" --sdk_root=/home/android/android_sdk/sdk
```